# How to remove empty value of array

Tags: php, arrays, input, laravel-4

i'm looking for a way to remove empty values from a array.

If you see the code below, i'm trying to remove the empty values that get passed through before attaching it to the model. But this hasn't turned out this way so far.

Ofcourse i searched the web before asking, and so i know that `trim()` doesn't give the desired effect aswell as `array_map()` and the code below.

Looking for solutions, thanks!

```
if(Input::get('addcategorie'))
    {
        $new_cats = array();
        foreach(
            explode(
                ',', Input::get('addcategorie')) as $categorie) 
        {
            $categorie = Categorie::firstOrCreate(array('name' => $categorie));
            foreach($new_cats as $newcat)
            if($newcat == ' ' || $newcat == '&nbsp;' || $newcat == ''){
                unset($newcat);
            }
            array_push($new_cats, $categorie->id);
        }
        $workshop->categories()->attach($new_cats); 
    }
```

Comment: use the array_values method.

Comment: Can you explain @MattBurrow?

Comment: @NicolasHenrard you posted link to Javascript question

Answer (score 4):

Just use `array_filter`:

```
$array = [
    0 => 'Patrick',
    1 => null,
    2 => 'Maciel',
    3 => '&nbsp',
    4 => '&nbsp;'
];

$filtered = array_filter($array);

$nbsp = array_filter($array, function($element) {
    return $element == '&nbsp' OR  $element == '&nbsp;';
});

$clean = array_diff($filtered, $nbsp);
```

The return is:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "Patrick"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Maciel"
}
```

This functions remove all **null, empty and &nbsp** from your arrays.

Comment: And what '&nbsp;' ? :)

Comment: Please note that also values which are an empty string or `false` get stripped out of the array. But I think it's the best solution for what the TS wanted to achieve.

Comment: Somehow it still adds the empty value as a new category. Could it be that the 'problem' is at 'firstOrCreate' ?

Comment: If i follow the code, it all makes sense and it should work, but somehow it doesn't. I'm quite certain the problem is at 'firstOrCreate'. I'll take a deeper look into that. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeroen maybe is your file encoding. Don't forget to mark the question as solved if is really that you said.

Comment: @PatrickMaciel i have no idea, tried almost everything.. I'll get a buddy of mine take a look at it. 

I have been unable to find the button or whatever to mark this question as solved.. Why is it hidden?

Comment: @Jeroen Under the "down vote" arrow. Anyway, you still have the problem yet? What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following code to `unset` in `foreach`:

```
foreach($new_cats as $key => $newcat) {
    if(yourCondition) {
        unset($new_cats[$key])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this also does the same. Empty values are not removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($new_cats as $newcat_i => $newcat) {
    $newcat = trim($newcat);

    if($newcat == '&nbsp;' || $newcat == '') {
        unset($new_cats[$newcat_i]);
    }
}
```

OR

```
$new_cats = array_filter(
    $new_cats, function ($value) {
        $value = trim($value);

        return $value != '' && $value != '&nbsp;';
    }
);
```

Final code is:

```
if(Input::get('addcategorie')) {
    $new_cats = array();
    foreach(explode(',', Input::get('addcategorie')) as $categorie) {
        $categorie = Categorie::firstOrCreate(array('name' => $categorie));

        array_push($new_cats, $categorie->id);
    }

    $new_cats = array_filter(
        $new_cats, function ($value) {
            $value = trim($value);

            return $value != '' && $value != '&nbsp;';
        }
    );

    $workshop->categories()->attach($new_cats);
}
```

Comment: tried both, still same result. Could it be that the 'problem' is at 'firstOrCreate' ?